# WPF combobox value and display text

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I'm used to doing things like

```
State.Items.Add(new ListItem { Text = "SomeState", Value = NumericIDofState });
```

Where State is a Listbox in ASP.NET.

How do i achieve the same with a WPF ComboBox? I do see a property called 'Content' in the ComboBoxItem object but how do i assign each item a value other than what's displayed to the user? Please help.

Comment: Could you check out my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34679195/3345644) and see if it's more useful for future readers than the one you've accepted?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

See these properties of combo:

- [DisplayMemberPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [SelectedValuePath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvaluepath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Please provide an example.

Answer (score 79):

[WPF Combobox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has:

- [`SelectedValuePath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvaluepath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property that specifies the path to the
  property that is used to determine the value of the `SelectedValue`
  property. It's similar to ASP.NET `ListItem`'s `Value` property.
- [`DisplayMemberPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property that defines a default template
  that describes how to display the data objects. It's similar to ASP.NET `ListItem`'s `Text` property.

Let's say you want your `Combobox` to show a collection of the following `KeyValuePair` objects:

```
private static readonly KeyValuePair<int, string>[] tripLengthList = {
    new KeyValuePair<int, string>(0, "0"),
    new KeyValuePair<int, string>(30, "30"), 
    new KeyValuePair<int, string>(50, "50"), 
    new KeyValuePair<int, string>(100, "100"), 
};
```

You define a property in your view model returning that collection:

```
public KeyValuePair<int, string>[] TripLengthList
{
    get
    {
        return tripLengthList;
    }
}
```

Then, your XAML for the `Combobox` would be:

```
<ComboBox
    SelectedValue="{Binding FilterService.TripLengthFrom, Mode=TwoWay}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding TripLengthList, Mode=OneTime}"
    SelectedValuePath="Key"
    DisplayMemberPath="Value" />
```

Where you set `SelectedValuePath` and `DisplayMemberPath` properties to the desired property names of the objects (`Key` and `Value` correspondingly) displaying by the `Combobox`.

**Or, if you really want to add items to `Combobox` in code behind** instead of using a binding, you can do it as well. For example:

```
<!--XAML-->
<ComboBox x:Name="ComboBoxFrom"
    SelectedValue="{Binding FilterService.TripLengthFrom, Mode=TwoWay}" />

// Code behind
public partial class FilterView : UserControl
{
    public FilterView()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.ComboBoxFrom.SelectedValuePath = "Key";
        this.ComboBoxFrom.DisplayMemberPath = "Value";
        this.ComboBoxFrom.Items.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(0, "0"));
        this.ComboBoxFrom.Items.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(30, "30"));
        this.ComboBoxFrom.Items.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(50, "50"));
        this.ComboBoxFrom.Items.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(100, "100"));
    }
```

Comment: I think this should be the chosen answer as it explains more on what can be done.

Comment: Unfortunately, OP hasn't visited SO after the answer was posted, Still waiting for him.

Comment: Note future WinUI 3 users: I needed to use an `IValueConverter` to get a similar thing working with integer binding.

Answer (score 59):

If you only want to expose a simple property in the viewmodel and handle the text for the choices in the view you can do a simple solution like this:

```
    <ComboBox SelectedValuePath="Tag" SelectedValue="{Binding YourIntProperty, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="First choice" Tag="0"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Second choice" Tag="1"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Third choice" Tag="2"/>
    </ComboBox>
```

Example with a bool property:

```
    <ComboBox SelectedValuePath="Tag" SelectedValue="{Binding IsActive, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="No" Tag="False"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Yes" Tag="True"/>
    </ComboBox>
```

**Type-verbose alternatives (original examples)**

Below are more verbose alternatives where the types are explicitly declared. Depending on your preferred style (or maybe some types that requires it), maybe it suits you better.

```
<ComboBox SelectedValuePath="Tag" SelectedValue="{Binding YourIntProperty, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="First choice">
        <ComboBoxItem.Tag>
            <sys:Int32>0</sys:Int32>
        </ComboBoxItem.Tag>
    </ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Second choice">
        <ComboBoxItem.Tag>
            <sys:Int32>1</sys:Int32>
        </ComboBoxItem.Tag>
    </ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Third choice">
        <ComboBoxItem.Tag>
            <sys:Int32>2</sys:Int32>
        </ComboBoxItem.Tag>
    </ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

Example with a bool property:

```
<ComboBox SelectedValuePath="Tag" SelectedValue="{Binding IsActive, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="No">
        <ComboBoxItem.Tag>
            <sys:Boolean>False</sys:Boolean>
        </ComboBoxItem.Tag>
    </ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Yes">
        <ComboBoxItem.Tag>
            <sys:Boolean>True</sys:Boolean>
        </ComboBoxItem.Tag>
    </ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

The sys namespace is declared as this:

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

Comment: great example with the boolean. just what i needed. i too dont like put all available UI strings (to select from) in my viewmodel, i want them in the XAML only.

Comment: why not Tag="True"?

Comment: @dovid thanks for the suggestion, I tested and it works. I have updated my answer with simplified examples, but keeping the old examples too in case needed for corner cases.

Comment: To get the value of  selected Tag use:
    string selectedTag=((ComboBoxItem)this.ComboBoxName.SelectedItem).Tag.ToString();
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309495

Answer (score 0):

If you skip the Value, then I think it's quite simple to add a new item into a ComboBox during runtime.

```
comboBox1.Items.Add("SomeText");

comboBox1.SelectedIndex = comboBox1.Items.Count - 1;
```

The `SelectedIndex` property is set to `Items.Count-1` so that the newly added item appears in the ComboBox as the selected item.

Comment: OP wants to know how to assign a value for each item displayed in the combobox/dropdown. This answer is talking about adding new items at runtime without regard to value, completely off point from what the question is asking.