# Get tag of selected item in WPF ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

I have combobox like this:

```
<ComboBox Name="ExpireAfterTimeComboBox" Margin="5" SelectedIndex="0">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="15 minutes" Tag="15" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="30 minutes" Tag="30" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="1 hour" Tag="60" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="1 day" Tag="1440" />
</ComboBox>
```

**How do I get Tag value in code?**

writing something like `ExpireAfterTimeComboBox.SelectedItem.Tag` doesn't work.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to cast it to a type of `ComboBoxItem`.

```
  var selectedTag = ((ComboBoxItem)ExpireAfterTimeComboBox.SelectedItem).Tag.ToString();
```

Comment: Not to be pedantic or anything, but why not just declare selectedTag as a string if you're calling the Object.ToString() method?

Comment: @djdanlib - No particular reason. When I started typing the answer, I used `var`, then at the end put `ToString` after remembering that `Tag` returns an object, not a string.

Answer (score 13):

If you could modify your Combobox declaration to the following:

```
<Combobox Name="ExpireAfterTimeComboBox" Margin="5" SelectedValuePath="Tag">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="15 minutes" Tag="15" IsSelected="True" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="30 minutes" Tag="30"  />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="1 hour" Tag="60"  />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="1 day" Tag="1440"  />
</Combobox>
```

You could retrieve the tag like so:

```
var selectedTag = ExpireAfterTimeComboBox.SelectedValue;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
string str =  ((ComboBoxItem)this.ExpireAfterTimeComboBox.SelectedItem).Tag.ToString();
```

in `SelectionChanged` event handler or in whatever function or event handler.