# How can I set the ComboBox value taken be an integer, whereas, some user friendly text displays on it?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

```
while (myReader.Read())
{
    int myStreamsId = myReader.GetInt32("streamid");
    string myStreams = myReader.GetString("streamname");
    //CmbStream.Items.Add(myStreams);


    this.CmbStream.SelectedValuePath = "Key";
    //this.CmbStream.DisplayMemberPath = "Value";
    this.CmbStream.Items.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(myStreamsId, myStreams));

}

<ComboBox Name="CmbStream" 
          SelectedValue="{Binding FillStreams.TripLengthFrom, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

I would like the ComboBox to take the integer i.e. streamid for my value, whereas, the characters/text drawn from streamname displays. How can I achieve that? I would be comfortable, for instance if someone select Aqua, and number 8 reads on a message box. Can someone aid in that?

[image: ComboBox]

In html, I am quite comfortable implementing this like demonstrated below:

```
<select><option value="streamid">streamname</option></select>
```

> The error persists, which property am I not putting right?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF combobox value and display text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775514/wpf-combobox-value-and-display-text).  You should always include the applicable technology (Winforms, WPF, WebForms etc etc etc).  And of course, search and research before posting

Comment: Specifically I dont't need those integers to display, but the underlying code to work with them. Can you explain that?

Comment: Did you trying setting the DisplayMemberPath to Value?

Comment: Yes Haitam, if I uncheck the comments on //this.CmbStream.DisplayMemberPath = "Value"; the ComboBox displays the streamname, but, when triggered it does not send the integer value.

Comment: What type is FillStreams.TripLengthFrom ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
while (myReader.Read())
{
    int myStreamsId = myReader.GetInt32("streamid");
    string myStreams = myReader.GetString("streamname");
    this.CmbStream.Items.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(myStreamsId, myStreams));
}

this.CmbStream.SelectedValuePath = "Key";
this.CmbStream.DisplayMemberPath = "Value";
```

...provided that the `FillStreams.TripLengthFrom` source property is an `int`.

Comment: Check the above edited problem. The code still takes the text not integer.

Comment: Where does the MessageBox come from? And again, what is FillStreams.TripLengthFrom?